# simpleperf failed to read symbols

Tags: android, linux, performance, perf

I used simpleperf to analyze performance issue for android. But it reported the following errors.

```
/mnt/androidwritable # simpleperf  report   --print-event-count |head -n 10
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [zram]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [ufs_qcom]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [qcom_dma_heaps]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [mem_hooks]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [qcom_iommu_util]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [arm_smmu]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [sched_walt]: File not found
simpleperf W dso.cpp:450] failed to read symbols from [msm_rtb]: File not found
```

All the **files not found** are android linux kernel modules. Then I though it did not know where the module files are located. So I used `--symfs` to provide the location of the module files. But it still reported the same error. Why?

Comment: Did it generate a perf.dat file? Did you use simpleperf record or similar before? Can you share more about the installation process and commands leading to 'simpleperf report'?

Comment: @Bahamas yes. it generated `perf.data` file. The file is generated by `simpleperf record -f 10000  -p  10191`.  `simpleperf` is installed on android by default.

Comment: Is the application you want to analyze written in Java?

Comment: @Bahamas Finally I figured it out. Files like `[zram]` come from vendor_ramdisk. vendor_ramdisk belongs to vendor_boot image in android. So those files reside on the vendor_boot image and there is no path to them.  Because vendor_boot imge is not mounted. So I have to download the vendor_ramdisk and push them to a mounted partition on the android device. Thank you anyway.